# Como adcionar uma imagem ao Kivy Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-kivy, kivy

Preciso adicionar uma imagem a minha tela e estava seguindo o que estava fazendo em todos os outros widgets.

Meu código:

```
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout1 = FloatLayout()
        button = Button(text='iniciar',
        pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.65}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        textinput1 = TextInput(pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.55}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        textinput2 = TextInput(pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.45}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        textinput3 = TextInput(pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.35}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        label1 = Label(text='Entrada:', pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.60}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        label2 = Label(text='Saida:', pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.50}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        label3 = Label(text='Objeto:',pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.40}, size_hint=(.25, .05))
        logo = Image(source='logoheader.png', pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.40})

        layout1.add_widget(button)
        layout1.add_widget(textinput1)
        layout1.add_widget(textinput2)
        layout1.add_widget(textinput3)
        layout1.add_widget(label1)
        layout1.add_widget(label2)
        layout1.add_widget(label3)
        layout1.add_widget(logo)

        return layout1


MainApp().run()
```

No entanto quando eu tento executar com o logo sou impedido com a seguinte mensagem:

```
logo = Image(source='logoheader.png', pos_hint={'x':.375, 'y':.40})
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'arg'
```

O código funciona perfeitamente quando comento a linha do logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontrei o erro,

Estava importando:

```
 from kivy.core.image import Image
```

Quando na verdade devia importar:

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image
```